# Restlet Request object doesn't contain authentication information

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, authentication, tomcat, restlet

The codebase I'm working with has two versions: the first (older) version uses v1.0.0 of the Restlet framework, and the latter (newer) version uses v2.2.2.

When a user queries both versions of my service with cURL and provides their username and password as a base64 encoded `String`, it works. Similarly, both versions accept the encoded `String` in the `Authorization: Basic ...` header.

Where they differ is when I attempt to call the service using `HttpURLConnection`. The former works, the latter doesn't.

This is the general idea of how the tool that calls my service works:

```
final String xx_userid = userid; // userid set above
final String xx_pwd = pwd;       // pwd set above
Authenticator.setDefault(new Authenticator() {
    protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
        return new PasswordAuthentication(
                xx_userid, xx_pwd.toCharArray());
    }
});

// ... some more code ...

URL url = new URL(url_string); // url_string is the endpoint of my service
HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();
conn.setRequestMethod("GET");
conn.setRequestProperty("Accept-Charset", "UTF-8");
conn.setRequestProperty("Accept", "text/xml");
```

The above code works for the older codebase (that is, I get a `200 OK` back as well as the expected XML response). However, for the new codebase, I get a `403 Unauthorized` back.

Here's the snippet in my new codebase that's supposed to get the username and password from the request:

```
@Override
protected boolean authenticate (Request request, Response response) {

    String user = null;
    String pass = null;

    user = request.getChallengeResponse().getIdentifier();
    pass = new String(request.getChallengeResponse().getSecret());

    // ... some more code ...

}
```

Both `user` and `pass` end up staying `null`, because the `getChallengeResponse()` method returns null.

Does anyone know why this code works for v1.0.0 of the Restlet framework, but not for v2.2.2? Or is there something else I'm missing?

Some other (probably irrelevant) information:

- The old codebase:

  - Is running in Tomcat v7.0.55
  - Is hosted on a RHEL7 machine
  - Doesn't have a load balancer
- The new codebase:

  - Is running in Tomcat v7.0.55
  - Is hosted on an EC2 instance (Amazon Linux AMI)
  - Uses Amazon's application load balancer (ALB) to point to the different EC2 instances
  - The load balancer has a different domain name than the service instances

Thanks in advance. Please let me know if there's any more information that I could provide to make this easier to debug.

Comment: I cannot imagine this being the issue, but are you using more than one EC2 inside of your target group right now? If so, try turning on stick sessions and/or temporarily scaling that back to one instance. Just trying to narrow down the changes that could have caused the issue. So far, it sounds like the following relevant details have changed: you're now behind an ALB (possibly multiple instances); you now have a different domain name between your Tomcat service and ALB; and you have upgraded from Restlet v1.0.0 to v2.2.2. Those are a lot of potentially relevant changes at once.

Comment: Right now I only have one EC2 spun up. I had the thought about the FQDN difference between the ALB and EC2, but I stopped worrying about it because (a) cURL, (b) the browser, and (c) using `Authorization: Basic ...` as a `HttpURLConnection` `requestHeader` all work fine. It's just this one edge case that doesn't work. I have a feeling that the Restlet version change is probably the culprit, but I don't know for sure. I'm very new to the framework, and the codebase I'm working with wasn't written by me.

Comment: Worst case scenario, I'm able to change the tool that's using my service to use the `requestHeader` instead of the above `Authenticator` code, but I don't want to do that if I don't have to, and if there's an underlying bug with my code that's preventing this behavior, I want to address it.